# Javascript uploading same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload

I have a problem on triggering the `onchange` event when choosing a file in a `filefield` which was chosen before. I need to be able to trigger the change event when uploading a file.

For example I want the following scenario to work:

**step 1)** User chooses test1.jpg

**step 2)** User clicks again and chooses test2.jpg

**step 3)** User clicks again and chooses test1.jpg again

In case of the last the file field doesn't trigger the `onchange` event any more. Is it possible to make it trigger? I've searched on Google and can't find a solution. I've tried to just replace the input field with a new one but this also doesn't work. For the last one, I did it in the following manner:

```
$('#picturesfile').replaceWith('<input type="file" name="filedata" id="picturesfile">');
```

UPDATE

I have tried it with jsfiddle and it does trigger the change event, the original problem is that the `onselect` event of `jcrop` isn't triggered I will close this question and proceed with finding a solution on that problem.

Comment: Could you create a Jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You could create an identical input box with jQuery amd replace the original one whenever a file is uploaded. This might clear any variables the browser has set for it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You want the file field to trigger after 3 choices?

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2ejG4/ but i noticed that it works on that!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `HTML` string `jQuery` parse and cache it in `$.cache` object if it less than 512 symbols. So you just needed to remove input and create it like this:

```
//create new input
var $newInput = $('<input>', {
    type : 'file',
    name : 'filedata',
    id : 'picturesfile'
});
//remove old and append to parentNode new
$('#picturesfile').remove().parent().append(newInput);
```